# Kotlin concrete class extending from abstract class and interface, with the interface using a method implemented in the abstract class

Tags: kotlin, architecture

I want to ask a question that I have some clues about, but I don't want to influence the answers I will get. I have the following class hierarchy:

```kotlin
abstract class MyAbstractClass { 
    fun displayStuff(id: String) {
        println("My id is $id.")
    }
}

interface MyInterface {
     fun displayThis() {
        displayStuff("some-value")
      }
     fun displayStuff(id: String) // Not implemented here
}

class MyConcreteClass(): MyAbstractClass(), MyInterface {
    fun doStuff() {
        displayThis()
    }
}

fun main() {    
    val result = MyConcreteClass()
    result.doStuff()
    result.displayStuff("id")
}
```

What's wrong with this design, and how do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain more on what is it that you want to fix?

Comment: `MyInterface` defines `displayStuff` without implementing it. I would expect that it is overridden in the `ConcreteClass`, but that is not the case. Instead the implementation is found in `MyAbstractClass`. This seems like an anti-pattern.

Comment: It is because you also `extend`  `MyAbstractClass`, if you remove that you will see the compiler error

Comment: Yes, but that will always be the case, I always want to extend `MyAbstractClass`.

Comment: I guess the question then is: how can I avoid not having to include `fun displayStuff(id: String)` in `MyInterface`?

Comment: So why don't you jut remove `MyInterface` and put all the methods in `MyAbstractClass` then?

Comment: Because I want to have the functionality in `displayThis` in a separate interface. Not every class that extends from `MyAbstractClass` will need it.

Comment: You should not call displayStuff from `MyInterface`. If display `displayStuff` is a function with complex logic it should be either in a separate class or function, in your case I don't see any major difference between `displayThis` and `displayStuff`, so not sure what is the use of `displayThis` function

Comment: It's just an example. In the real code these methods are not as simple. The point is that the method in the interface `displayThis` is about a separate concern from the abstract class, so it needs to be kept separately.

Comment: If its a separate concern then it should not be calling `displayStuff ` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably not be a bad idea to extract the `displayStuff` into another interface. Then `MyAbstractClass` and `MyInterface` can both derive from the same interface.
One overrides the `displayStuff` function, hence providing something like an abstract base implementation for the interface.
The other one is using the function in a specific way, thereby extending the functionality of the interface.

```
interface DisplayStuff {
    fun displayStuff(id: String)
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass: DisplayStuff {
    override fun displayStuff(id: String) = println("My id is $id.")
}

interface MyInterface : DisplayStuff {
    fun displayThis() = displayStuff("some-value")
}
```